# Difference plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't know the name of this type of plot (comments around this are welcomed).  Essentially it is a barplot with glyphs that are filled to indicate a loss/gain.  The glyph is arrow like encoding information about direction, magnitude, and allowing the bar geom under to be seen.

[image]

This looks interesting but can't think of how to do it in `ggplot2` (grid frame work).  How could we recreate this plot in ggplot2/grid framework (base solutions welcomed as well for completeness of question).  Specifically the glyphs, not the text as this is pretty straight forward in ggplot2 already.

Here is some code to create data and traditional overlaid & coordinate flipped dodged bar plots and line graphs to show typical ways of visualizing this type of data.

```
set.seed(10)
x <- sample(30:60, 12)
y <- jitter(x, 60)

library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(
    year = rep(2012:2013, each=12),
    month = rep(month.abb, 2),
    profit = c(x, y)
)


ggplot() + 
geom_bar(data=subset(dat, year==2012), aes(x=month, weight=profit)) +
geom_bar(data=subset(dat, year==2013), aes(x=month, weight=profit), width=.5, fill="red")

ggplot(dat, aes(x=month, fill=factor(year))) +
    geom_bar(position="dodge", aes(weight=profit)) +
    coord_flip

ggplot(dat, aes(x=month, y=profit, group = year, color=factor(year))) +
    geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `annotation_custom` with `polygonGrob`'s might work.

Comment: Your examples are better than the original graph. The glyphs are confusing at best, misleading at worst.

Comment: Like @thelatemail said!  Plotting two disparate sets of data (value and deltas) on one graph is generally not recommended because it's hard to decipher.

Comment: @thelatemail It wasn't a question of quality as such a question would be inappropriate for SO but a question of how.  It was interesting.  I just like being able to do things and putting more tricks in my bag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example, perhaps there are other ways though,

```
dat <- data.frame(
  year = rep(2012:2013, each=12),
  month = factor(rep(1:12, 2), labels=month.abb),
  profit = c(x, y)
)
dat2 <- reshape2::dcast(dat, month~ year, value.var = "profit")
names(dat2)[2:3] <- paste0("Y", names(dat2)[2:3])

ggplot(dat2) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=month, y = Y2012), stat = "identity", fill = "grey80", width = 0.6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=as.numeric(month)-0.4, xend = as.numeric(month)+0.4, y = Y2013, yend = Y2013)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = month, xend = month, y = Y2013, yend = Y2012, colour = Y2013 < Y2012), 
               arrow = arrow(60, type = "closed", length = unit(0.1, "inches")), size = 1.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. +1 I agree with @thelatemail this may not be the best approach if looking for larger patterns. I think the line charts would do that better. But the graph here actually improves on the design I demoed in that the arrows cover less of the bar geom. If one wanted more accurate month by month comparisons this approach may have some benefits. I know of no empirical study that has compared perception of this sort of graph for such a task but I can see it may have merits in allowing one to quickly identify month variability and magnitude without losing info about the overall profit.

Comment: One can concentrate on either the colored arrow or give attention to the bars or attention to the difference line (don't know the technical name for these, but year 2 horizontal lines) without being too distracted by the competing preattentive attributes. graph quality and design is about intended purpose. I can see that this graph type may have merit under the right circumstances. Thank you for the approach.